# Flutter - Getting the image path of GridView image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to share an image that has been loaded into a GridView previously with the following code:

```
return FocusedMenuHolder(
            blurSize: 2,
            blurBackgroundColor: Colors.black12,
            menuWidth: 200,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            onPressed: (){},
            menuItems: <FocusedMenuItem>[
              FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Share"),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.share) ,onPressed: (){}),
              FocusedMenuItem(title: Text("Delete",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),),trailingIcon: Icon(Icons.delete,color: Colors.redAccent,) ,onPressed: (){}),
            ],
            child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: FileImage(File(localFiles[index])), fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            );
```

Then on a long press from the opened FocusedMenu, I would like to pick share and share that file with the flutters share package. I however have no idea how I should go on about getting the path of the file loaded in the FocusedMenuHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list is "localFiles", and you want to share the path, meaning the path stored locally on your device. In your on pressed:

Use your share function that you want, and pass this path to it:
`localFiles[index].filePath`.